# compare two results and print the missing part if exist

Tags: bash, unix

May be I'm asking a trivial question, but can't find the right way.

I'm ssh'ing in several servers and comparing expected nfs mounts from /etc/fstab with existing mounts from /proc/mounts.

```
VAR1=$(awk '!/^#/ && $3 == "nfs" {print $2}'  /etc/fstab)
VAR2=$(awk '!/^#/ && $3 ~ /nfs[34]/ && $1 !~ /gfs/ {print $2}'  /proc/mounts)
```

For example, from `/etc/fstab` :

```
  /data1 
  /data2
  /data3
```

And from `/proc/mounts` :

```
  /data1
  /data2
```

If all mounts exist and mounted I have to print that all OK ,and if some missing to print them out and remount.

I tried to work for comparison with :

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file1 file2 ( but not works with $VAR1/$VAR2 ).
```

With nested loops also didn't success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use that awk pattern on the original files (`/etc/fstab` and `/proc/mounts`) to get your list of missing mountpoints. You probably want to use `$3` in that array in the first loop.

Comment: @Etan sorry, could you elaborate more

Comment: You said you tried to use that awk pattern for this purpose but it doesn't work on variables. That's true, but it does work on filenames and you just wrote two awk scripts that process the filenames. Instead of running awk three times just run it once. Give it the two files as arguments and do the `FNR==NR` mapping loop for the first one and the check for the second and only print out lines that fail the check.

Comment: Something like `awk '/^#/ {next} (FNR==NR) && ($3 == "nfs") {seen[$3]; next} ($3 == "nfs") && (!seen[$3]) {print $2}'  /etc/fstab /proc/mounts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the missing mounts like this:

```
comm -23 <(printf '%s\n' "$VAR1") <(printf '%s\n' "$VAR2")
```

This prints the lines which are only in `$VAR1`.

Or as a one-liner:

```
comm -23 <(awk '!/^#/ && $3 == "nfs" {print $2}' /etc/fstab) <(awk '!/^#/ && $3 ~ /nfs[34]/ && $1 !~ /gfs/ {print $2}' /proc/mounts)
```

Comment: I think you'd have to add the newlines back in, e.g. `echo $VAR1 | sed -r 's/\s+/\n/'`, for the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result from `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` this way:

```
for i in $VAR1 $VAR2; do echo $i; done \
    | sort | uniq -c | awk '/\s+1/ {print $2}'
```

Basically, we're looking for the directories that are only mentioned once. There may be a more elegant way to do this, but that should get you what you want.